# Male USB C to Female USB C right-angle adapter

Tags: usb

It's simple enough to imagine. I have a phone dock that has no connector of its own, but a place to thread a cable into it. I have a USB C male-to-male cable that goes from the wall charger to this dock. In order to preserve the cable's interior, I want to attach to the end of it a right-angle-adapter so it can be pointed up and into the phone's charging port without bending the cable, itself.

However, after many hours of searching between me and two other friends, we have come up dry. **Does such a thing exist, yet?**

---

It's worth noting we did find some "right angle adapters" that turned sideways, but this won't work for this setup; it needs to turn up or down, not left or right.

Comment: Did you ever find anything? I have this exact need at the moment, too

Comment: @KOGI Not yet, but I'll post an answer if I do!